# Simple Form Blank Label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

So im using Simple Form for my Rails App, and i need to get rid of the label on every input that comes with with simple form.

I Tried:
  <%= f.input :email, class: "login-field", label: "" %>
leaving the label blank, but this didn't work.

I'm relatively new to rails, could somebody explain how to achieve this ?

Edit:
I'm trying to achieve this format:

```
<input type="password" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="Password" id="login-pass" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Have you tried `label:false` instead of `label:""`:

```
<%= f.input :email, class: "login-field", label: false %>
```

Comment: But I still want the label's container to show up, just without any text inside. I tried `:label => "&nbsp"` but the &nbsp; shows up!

Answer (score 21):

Old question but it worked for me, @Josh M:

```
<%= f.input :email, class: "login-field", label: '&nbsp;'.html_safe %>
```

simple_form (3.0.2)

Comment: @Josh M was missing .html_safe

Answer (score 6):

I think the way to go is `label: false`
Also in `simple_form_for` you may pass `defaults: {label: false}` to disable label for all fields in this form.